# Parallelize the training of deep learning model using Flask

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, celery

Let's say I'm creating the following service:
`@app.route('/train_model' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])`

Suppose multiple people want to train the model(using different datasets) using the above service.

So, I need to incorporate parallelism now.

So the following things has to be added

**Note**: The following is not the complete code

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker = 'redis://localhost:6379',#amqp://localhost//,
                    backend = 'redis://localhost:6379')
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

app = Flask(__name__)
celery = make_celery(app)

@app.route('/train_qna_service' , methods = ['GET' , 'POST'])
def uploadfile():
    train_model.delay()

@celery.task(name='main.train_model')
def train_model():
    # do appropriate task to train the model
    pass
```

But if I use `train_model.delay()`, I won't get the result. If I'll use `train_model.wait()`, other people can not hit the service. If I use `multiprocessing` module, still other people can not hit the service.

What is the best way to support multiple training request using flask service ?